# Overloading -> operator in C++ to return custom object

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<T> p) : p(p)
    {
    }

    T* operator->() const {
        return p.get();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> p;
};
class B{
    public:
    void doSomething() {

    }
};


int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_shared<B>();
    auto y = new A<B>(x);
    y->doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

The way I overloaded the pointer operator `->` it should return `T*` (in this case `B*`) which would in turn have `doSomething` but I get

```
main.cpp:40:4: error: ‘class A’ has no member named ‘doSomething’
 y->doSomething();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

but in fact `->` returns a pointer to `B`, not `A`

Comment: 1) Your operator is never invoked. Did you mean to write `(*y)->doSomething();` 2) Why use of `new` in the first place, instead of just `A<B> y (x);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the type of `y` is `A<B>*` and not `A<B>`. The `operator->` can be overloaded for the objects. Pointers are provided the built-in `->` only.

Following should work in your case:

```
(*y)->doSomething();
```

On a side note, it's weird to have `new` for no good reason, when you already using a `shared_ptr<>` for some other allocation. :-)